# Can I have a parent scroll container ignore overflow:visible content?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an HTML page which is comprised of two sections; header and body. Rather than use a position:fixed header and allowing the whole page to scroll, I have used a normal header and made the body a scroll container. This is because there are fixed/sticky elements in the body which need to stick to the bottom of the header (and also due to problems with dynamic sizing of the header and body). The problem is that we have various UI elements which appear smooth across the header/body boundary. Our application's layout is responsive to screen size, and now the body may have a scrollbar, but the header doesn't, so they don't quite line up.

I have fixed this problem by having the body elements have a reduced width, and then using a position:absolute background div at the end, to overlap where the scrollbar would go, with the same background colours as the main UI element so they appear to be part of it. This means the header and body would keep a consistent width regardless of scrollbar.

The basic issue with this solution is that when the vertical scrollbar is shown, the browser also shows a horizontal scrollbar so that the user can "see" my placeholder background div, even though it doesn't occupy any of the width. I've tried a few different values for stuff like overflow, etc, but what it really boils down to is that none of them can show the placeholder divs when the scrollbar is not present without making a mess when it is present. There doesn't seem to be a CSS property for when the scrollbar is shown so that you can change the CSS as needed.

I've looked at e.g. scrollbar-gutter but we can't really use this as we need to continue supporting Chromium 88 as well as Firefox, iOS Safari, and similar. overflow:overlay would be ideal but isn't a well supported feature.

Some have suggested a mix of position:relative and position:fixed, but if I apply the right styles to get the element into the right place when there is no scrollbar, then it still causes the same issue when there is one.

Please see the following snippet (I tried the inbuilt one but it doesn't seem to work super well with content that requires scrollbars and such). I've created simple fixed-height divs to demonstrate the different content that I'm dealing with right now. The blue boxes should appear to go all the way across but don't need interaction right on that last bit. The red and green boxes should always line up, even though their layout is width-dependent and only the bottom section of the page scrolls if you shrink it down. These goals are achieved but when you shrink the page so that the vertical scrollbar is needed, the horizontal scrollbar also appears.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;margin:0">
        <div style="height:200px;flex-shrink:0; max-width:calc(100vw - 17px)">
             <div style="height:100px;background:blue; width:100%; position:relative">
                 <div style="position:absolute;width:17px;right:-17px;height:100%;background:blue"></div>
             </div>
             <div style="height:100px;background:red;margin-left:200px; width:50%"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; overflow: auto;">
            <div style="max-width:calc(100vw - 17px)">
                <div style="height: 100px;background:green;margin-left:200px; width:50%"></div>
                <div style="height: 100px;background:blue; width:100%; position:relative">
                    <div style="position:absolute;width:17px;right:-17px;height:100%;background:blue"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.